# iOS Notification - Can Object Parameter Be Any Arbitrary Object?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

Both the `addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)` and `post(name:object:userInfo:)` methods include an "object" parameter.  The corresponding documentation describes the object parameter as being, "[t]he object whose notifications the observer wants to receive; that is, only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the observer," and "[t]he object posting the notification."  These descriptions give me the impression that the object "parameter," if not set to nil, must be the same object from which the `post()` method is called.

However, in practice, it appears that the `post()` method can include any arbitrary object as its object parameter.  At the same time, the `addObserver()` method can be set with any arbitrary object.  Thus, if the `post()` and `addObserver()` methods refer to the same arbitrary object (and with the same Notification.Name), they should function to send and receive.  In experiments, this seems to work just fine.

In the following example, Observer registers to receive a particular notice from sender arbitrary.  However, Store is the one that posts the notice.  In posting the notice, Store includes the same instant of arbitrary as the object that is the "sender." Observer receives the notice.  This works even though Store, rather than arbitrary, is the "sender" of the notice.

```
class ArbitraryData {
    var data: [String] = ["some handy info"]
    func getMoreInfo() {
        Store.aSyncReadData(self)
    }
}

class Observer {   
    let arbitrary = ArbitraryData()
    func initiate() { 

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleNotice), 
        name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "eventHappenedNotice"),
        object: arbitrary)

        ... do stuff ...

        arbitrary.getMoreInfo()
    }

    func handleNotice(notice: Notification) { 
        for infoItem in arbitrary.data {
            print(infoItem)
        }
    }
}

class Store {        
    static func aSyncReadData(dataObject: ArbitraryData) {

        ServerAPI.getSomeDataFromPersistentStore(completionHandler: { newData in
            dataObject.data.append(newData)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "eventHappenedNotice"), 
            object: dataObject)
        })
    }
}
```

**Is this use of an arbitrary object part of the intended functionality, and is it safe?  Or, is use of an arbitrary object a kluge that is likely to lead to some kind of failure that may be difficult to debug later?**

Comment: @MuseerAnsari - Thank you for the edits.  I will endeavor to follow the style guide more closely going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood a little bit what you are doing.

First of all in your example, `Store` is not the one who posts the notification, it's `ArbitraryData` the one who posts the notification.

To explain a little bit more:

If you use the `object` parameter when you register/post a notification, the notification will be received/sent only if the object used to register is equal to the object posting the notification. So if you use both `name` and `object` parameters to register/send notification, `name` and `object` must be equal in order to have a proper notification communication.

If you don't use the `object` parameter, then the only check is applied to name.

So for example, in your case if you use two different instances of `ArbitraryData` which are not equal, one for register and one for posting, your notification won't work.

Comment: thank you.  I think you've helped me understand the intent.  To be sure:   Is it correct to say, that, by passing the arbitraryData object into `post()` as the "object" parameter, that determines arbitraryData to be the object that is posting the notice?  As a corollary, is it correct to say that, if nil is passed to the `post()` mehtod, then there is no object posting the notice?

Comment: In my opinion, both statements are safe and true.